# How to select all table names where a 'user_id' column is?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to select all table names where one of columns has a name **user_id**.

Is it possible in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select table_name
from information_schema.columns
where column_name = 'user_id'
```

It should work OK.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to include the **schema name**. Your table name can be ambiguous without it. May even lead to harmful confusion:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE column_name = 'user_id';
```

The information schema is only good if you need cross-RDBMS portability, which is rarely needed and rarely works. I'd rather query the catalog tables directly. Faster and shorter:

```
SELECT attrelid::regclass
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attname = 'user_id';
```

And be sure that you are connected to the same database.